# Dynamic HTML Menu?

Tags: html

I want my website to consist purely of HTML, CSS and JS, no Php.

I'm used to doing this in php, is there any way to do this in html?:

```
<?php include 'menu.php' ?>
```

Comment: Not with vanilla HTML. JS templating engines may be the way to go for you. One example is Jade: http://jade-lang.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Can't do it purely in HTML.

If you wanted to go old-school, you could setup some server-side includes:

```
<!--#include file="menu.html" -->
```

Because you have shared external JS files, that's one avenue to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: I thought so, guess I'll have to stick with php. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with jQuery using the following syntax:

```
$(function(){
    $('#header-region').load('menu.html');
});
```